# Check if row contains checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if row in table contains checkbox, no matter if it is checked. If yes on mouseover action change its background color on some.
My table is indicated with class .parts.
Below is part of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".parts tbody tr:contains('input:checkbox')").on('mouseover', function () {
          $(this).css("background-color", "#EFF3F7");
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) looks for *text*. You're looking for [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), *without* the internal quotes:

```
$(".parts tbody tr:has(input:checkbox)").on('mouseover', ...
// ----------------^---^-------------^
```

Gratuitous live example:

```js
$(".parts tbody tr:has(input:checkbox)").on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#EFF3F7");
});
```

```css
.parts, .parts td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table class="parts">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>checkbox</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>has checkbox</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>has checkbox</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You'll probably also want a `mouseout` handler to change it back. (Or perhaps `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, or indeed [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').parents(".parts").on('mouseover', 
    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#EFF3F7");
    });
});
```

This should work for you if you want to bind the event on `parts` class.

Comment: That'll put the handler on the *table*, not the individual rows. You'd need `$(".parts input:checkbox").parents(".parts tr").on(...` (note using `.parts` in both places, to avoid hooking any ancestor `tr` that might contain the table).

Comment: (Or of course, delegated: `$(".parts input:checkbox").closest(".parts").on("mouseover", "tr", ...`)